# How do I get or set a value inside/outside an extension

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I am new to Swift and I am trying to understand how could a class get a value inside an extension.

I have two problems but they are similar to each other, but first I will explain my project. I am using 2 controllers (**MainViewController** and **FactsViewController**) that we could say first controller and second controller. The third file is a `CollectionViewCell` because I am using a collection view on my project.

So, for the first problem, I am trying to call `prepareForSegue` method to send a value to **FactsViewController**. I kinda have all the method done, but I don't know how could a I collect the indexPath from the extension to send the right information to my second screen. This is the method on my **MainViewController**:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
  let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FactViewController
  // getting the value associated with a variable here on this line
  destinationVC.receivedValue = // a possible variable with the right result
}
```

This is how my `CollectionViewCell` file looks like:

```
class FactsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbFactsText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbCategories: UILabel!
    
    func setup(with facts: FactsData?, index: Int) {
        
        let result = facts!.result[index]
        
        lbFactsText.text = result.value
        print(result.value)
        if let category = result.categories.first {
            
            lbCategories.text = category!.uppercased()
            lbCategories.sizeToFit()
        } else {
            
            lbCategories.text = "UNCATEGORIZED"
            lbCategories.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

I don't if StackOverFlow will let I list all the code to be precise but here is the list of the extensions I am using:

```
extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}
```

(Note that there are code inside those extension methods, it just listed empty just to show methods I am using).

How could I for example get a fact[result].value to transfer there on my `prepareForSegue` method? Also, as I mentioned two problems, how could I sum all heights of my `lbFactsText` and `lbCategories` to return on `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. I am really confused, I heard that `objc_setAssociatedObject` or `objc_getAssociatedObject` could do this but I don't understand how to use it, it is really the correct way use this two methods? I got from this site: https://marcosantadev.com/stored-properties-swift-extensions/

Please let me know if you need me to list full details of the extensions.

Comment: Add a property to your MainViewController that you read in prepareForSegue and write to in your extension method.

Comment: Now I see that also my `prepareForSegue` is not being called at all. My method `didSelectItemAt` is performing a `performSegue`, don't now if it is the problem.

Comment: Some how it works, but I identified that some crucial extensions protocol are being called before the ones that I need the values. I can not sum `lbFactsText` and `lbCategories` to use on `sizeForItemAt` because `sizeForItemAt` is called before `cellForItemAt`, then the app crash.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Joakim Danielson, it worked. I had to write a property on my controller class to store the value inside the extension.